# Dynamically set log4net filename in a web service log

Tags: c#, wcf, f#, log4net

I'm using log4net in a web service and I want to set the log filename per request based on a user parameter sent in the request itself.

I've defined a property in the config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ClaimLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\projects\reports\ClaimRpt\Log\ClaimLog_%property{UserNameWCF}.txt" />
```

and set it at the beginning of my web method

```
type ClaimServiceF() = 


    let log = LogManager.GetLogger("ClaimServiceF")
```

...

```
member this.BeginReport(sel: Model.Selection) : Model.RptResponse =
    GlobalContext.Properties.Item("UserNameWCF") <- sel.User
    let rptResp = new Model.RptResponse()
    log.Info("Started")
    match sel with
    | null ->
```

I'm wrapping the F# library (SrvImplF.dll) in a C# WCF project ([why?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b85810d7-5f89-4614-8151-64e825390c83/async-web-service-in-f-30-and-visual-studio-community-2015-targeting-net-40?forum=fsharpgeneral)) and testing it with the WCF Test Client of Visual Studio.

But the log filename remains at its initial value `ClaimLog_(null).txt` even though I can set a breakpoint and see that `sel.User` is correctly filled

I've also tried with the AppSettings type provider from appSettings

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="my_service_log" value="C:\projects\reports\ClaimRpt\Log\ClaimLog_{UserNameWCF}.txt" />
  </appSettings>
```

by coding

```
open FSharp.Configuration
type Settings = AppSettings<"app.config">
```

...

```
let appender = LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders() |> Seq.find(fun x -> x.Name.Equals("ClaimLog") ) :?> log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender
```

...

```
appender.File <- Settings.MyServiceLog.Replace("{UserNameWCF}",sel.User)
```

but - besides the fact that I need to create a fictitious app.config under the dll and duplicate the app key there because the type provider doesn't see the app.config of the wrapping project - it throws the exception

> Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in SrvImplF.dll
>   An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in
>   SrvImplF.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   The type initializer for
>   'FSharp.Configuration.AppSettingsTypeProvider' threw an exception.

I think this last is only a trivial error in my type provider configuration, anyway also directly entering the value

```
        let configFile = "C:\reports\ClaimRpt\Log\ClaimLog_{UserNameWCF}.txt" //Settings.MyServiceLog
        appender.File <- configFile.Replace("{UserNameWCF}",sel.User)
```

there is no exception but the log filename remains unchanged `ClaimLog_(null).txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `LogManager.GetLogger("ClaimServiceF")` *after* setting the property.

Note that your approach is prone to race conditions. If multiple clients access your application at the same time you might end up logging to the wrong file. Assume e.g. the following execution order of two parallel requests:

```
// incoming request A
GlobalContext.Properties.Item("UserNameWCF") <- sel.User

// incoming request B
GlobalContext.Properties.Item("UserNameWCF") <- sel.User

// request A
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("ClaimServiceF")
// logger has 'UserNameWCF' set to 'sel.User' of request B
```

To fix that issue consider using [ThreadContext](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html) which 'attaches' or 'scopes' the property to a request, as each request is handled by a separate (pooled, reused) thread.
Pay extra attention if you use `async`/`await` to set the property and fetch the logger within the same thread.

Comment: @GoFunctional Do you have any further details of the exception thrown by the TypeProvider? Also, as per StackOverflow rules the type provider issue should be a separate question. I recommend you edit yours and create a new one.

Comment: @GoFunctional yes, exactly. ThreadContext mitigates said problem. As for the stacked contexts: this provides even more / finer grained control over property scopes. For your use case this is unnecessary complexity, IMO.